# Openstack Services Status Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, services, cloud, openstack

i installed openstack on Ubuntu server LTS 20.4 . in centos 7.9 usually i install a package `openstack-utils` which let me run `openstack-status` and i can see all services status at same time.

how should i achieve the same thing in ubuntu server ?

what package should i use ?

Comment: I don't know if that package is available, I just remember that in older versions I used to have it in openSUSE but at some point it wasn't there anymore, so I just wrote my own script to see an overall cluster status. As far as I remember the `openstack-status` command was just a list of statements, but it's been a few years since I last used that, so I might be wrong. But you could easily check what the script does, couldn't you? And then adapt it to your needs.

Comment: hmm. that's a good idea i will definitely try that but i consider it as my last option i am a rookie in cloud and i just know some basic scripting